# Coordinate points falling off map

Tags: qgis, ndvi

I'm trying to extract values from a map figure (NDVIs in this case). My layer with the point coordinates as Lat/Long, added as a CSV file, has the same CRS as the map layer (WGS 84 / UTM zone 36N). But the points keep falling off the map (see attached screen capture).

The format of the coordinates being shown at the bottom of the window (e.g., this point which is in the middle east: 423.63203,-115.09483) is not familiar to me and
so I wasn't able to convert the coordinates in my CSV file to this other format.

CVS coordinate data:
[image]

Importing map raster:
[image]

Map CRS:
[image]

Importing CVS of coordinates:
[image]

CRS of CVS coordinate layer:
[image]

Comment: Something went wrong when you imported stuff. Please provide example data and the CRS of the NDVI-image.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: If your points are in lat/lon it cant be in UTM at the same time. I guess this is a classical mixup of coordinate systems. Always choose the CRS the layer is really in when adding a layer. Do not mix it up with other layers CRS or the canvas CRS. However, to provide more precise help, please add further details like an example of your coordinates and your chosen settings when importing the layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed this answer entirely because of the elaborations you've added.

The problem is very simple. Your NDVI raster doesn't have any coordinate information included. You must either download a `.tiff` NDVI raster in which has the coordinate information, or `georeference` your `png` image and export it as a `tiff` or a `jpeg + world file`.

**GOOD LUCK**

Comment: First thing thanks everyone, greatly appreciated! Ash, I tried reprojecting my coordinates and couldn't make it work. I'm adding more info as screen captures into my original post, as per Erik's and MrXsquared comments:

Comment: Your NDVI is a `png` raster. So it couldn't store any coordinate in itself. Typically, coordinates for the four corners of a raster should be stored either inside the raster or as a supporting text file. Generally, `tif` and `bil` files store these internally. But `jpeg` or `png` must be accompanied by a supporting coordinate file stored at the same place and the same name, only a different format suffix suck as `.wld` for instance.

Comment: Understood now, thanks so much!

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer. Thank you.